# Sending and retrieving data from datastore with mobile backend starter

Tags: android, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm trying to use Mobile Backend Starter in my Android application. In order to do that I need to store some data in the Datastore.

I'm using the provided object `CloudEntity` but I can only consistently insert and read `String`.

That's the example code I used to send data:

```
CloudEntity entity = new CloudEntity(TEST_KIND_NAME);

entity.put(KEY_DATE, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
entity.put(KEY_CALENDAR, Calendar.getInstance());
entity.put(KEY_LONG,  Long.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE));                
entity.put(KEY_INTEGER, Integer.valueOf(Integer.MAX_VALUE));
getCloudBackend().insert(entity, simpleHandler);
```

and this is how I read the data back (next code goes in the `onComplete` in the `CloudBackendHandler`:

```
StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer();
strBuff.append("Inserted: \n");
strBuff.append("\tId = " + result.getId() + "\n");
Object o;
o = result.get(KEY_DATE);            
strBuff.append("\tDate was retrieved as : " + ((o == null)? "null" : o.getClass().getName()) + "\n");
        
o = result.get(KEY_CALENDAR);
strBuff.append("\tCalendar was retrieved as : " + ((o == null)? "null" : o.getClass().getName()) + "\n");
        
o = result.get(KEY_LONG);
strBuff.append("\tLong was retrieved as : " + ((o == null)? "null" : o.getClass().getName()) + "\n");
        
o = result.get(KEY_INTEGER);
strBuff.append("\tInteger was retrieved as : " + ((o == null)? "null" : o.getClass().getName()) + "\n");
        
o = result.get(KEY_BOOLEAN);
strBuff.append("\tBoolean was retrieved as : " + ((o == null)? "null" : o.getClass().getName()) + "\n");
mTvInfo.setText(strBuff);
```

And what I get as result is:

Data inserted as `Date` and `Calendar` returns `null`.

Data inserted as `Integer` returns `BigDecimal`.

Data inserted as `Long`returns a `String`.

My question is: Can I send (and read back) other data than `String? And if so. How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some time experimenting with the Android Mobile Backed Starter I found a link to a "sort of" (very limited) documentation: [Mobile Backend Starter](https://devsite.googleplex.com/cloud/samples/mbs/).

What I found is that if you send an `Integer` (and if I trust de documentation a `Float` or a  `Double`) it is stored in the **DataStore** as a *numeric* field. And is returned as a `BigDecimal` when you send a query (through `ClouldQuery`).

Nevertheless, if you pass a `Long` as a property in your `CloudEntity`, it will be stored as a `String` in the **DataStore** and returned as such. And this is not trivial, as `String` fields has limitations on allowed comparisons.

If you send a [`DateTime`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/google-api-client/src/com/google/api/client/util/DateTime.java?r=ef7eabc5cb37e2a2199b4040ec92ba4d18cb9553), the documentation tells you that you will get back a `String`, but don't tells you that it will be stored in the **DataStore** as a `String` too.

This is important because you can't do all the comparisons with `String`s. It is only allowed the equality (and ne) comparison (you can't test a greater than filter over a `String` property in your queries). So you can't store *timestamps* as `Long` (will be converted to `String` and you won't be able to compare them) and you can't set timestamps as `DateTime` for the same reason. **And you just can't store Date nor Calendar objects.**

Anyway every `CloudEntity` has two `DateTime` porperties by default `CloudEntity.PROP_CREATED_AT` and `CloudEntity.PROP_UPDATED_AT`. You can set a query filter with this fields. To do so you need to set the filter as

```
CloudQuery myQuery = new CloudQuery(<your kind name>);
myQuery.set<things>...
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(<the time you want>);
myQuery.setFilter(F.gt(CloudEntity.PROP_UPDATED_AT, dateTime));
```

You **need to use a** `DateTime` for the comparison. If you are courious, you can **NOT** use `Date` instead of `DateTime` for this comparation. You would get this error:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
    "code": 400,
    "errors": [
    {
       "domain": "global",
       "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: _updatedAt:java.util.LinkedHashMap is not a supported property type.",
       "reason": "badRequest"
    }
    ],
    "message": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: _updatedAt: java.util.LinkedHashMap is not a supported property type."
...
```

Other weird thing is that, aparently, you **can not** do comparisons with `dateTime = new DateTime(0)` (i.e. 1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00) as the backend receives the query as:

```
query: (_kindName:"Data") AND ( _updatedAt > "1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00" ), schema: {_kindName=STRING, _updatedAt=STRING}
```

Won't give any error but will return nothing `list: result: null`. Looks like it treats the comparison as a `String`.  If you use `DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(1)` instead, you will send a query as:

```
list: executing query: {filterDto={operator=GT, values=[_updatedAt, 1970-01-01T01:00:00.001+01:00]},
```

looks the same as before but the backend will execute the query as:

```
 query: (_kindName:"Data") AND ( _updatedAt > 1 ), schema: {_kindName=STRING, _updatedAt=DOUBLE}
```

As I see a `DOUBLE` I tried submit a `Double` instead a `DateTime`, but it doesn't work (no error but not result).

**But, GOOD NEWS EVERYONE! We can do the comparison with an** `Integer` as:

```
Integer anInteger = Integer.valueOf(0);
myQuery.setFilter(F.gt(CloudEntity.PROP_UPDATED_AT, anInteger));
```

the backend sees:

```
query: (_kindName:"Data") AND ( _updatedAt > 0 ), schema: {_kindName=STRING, _updatedAt=INT32}
```

and we'll get the expected value (all the entities updated since 1970-01-01T01:00:00.000+01:00)

Sorry for my mistakes (my english isn't good) and I hope this can help someone and, at least, save him some time.